# Using distributive law of product operator in conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, independence

Suppose I know the following to be true: $$ f(\mathbf{x} | \mathbf{u}) = \prod_{j=1}^M f(x_j | u_j) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [1] $$

From this statement, is it correct to conclude that the random vector $\mathbf{U} = (U_1, U_2, ... U_m)$ has components which are all independent of each other?  My derivation is as follows:
$$ \frac{f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u})}{f(\mathbf{u})} = f(\mathbf{x} | \mathbf{u}) = \prod_{j=1}^M f(x_j | u_j) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  [2] $$
Then, using the rule of conditional probability, $f(x_j|u_j) = \frac{f(x_j,u_j)}{f(u_j)}$, I get
$$ \frac{f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u})}{f(\mathbf{u})} = f(\mathbf{x} | \mathbf{u}) = \prod_{j=1}^M f(x_j | u_j) = \prod_{j=1}^M \frac{f(x_j,u_j)}{f(u_j)} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  [3] $$

The next step is where I am wondering if this is statistically valid:

$$ \prod_{j=1}^M \frac{f(x_j,u_j)}{f(u_j)} = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^M f(x_j,u_j)}{\prod_{j=1}^M f(u_j)}    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [4] $$

If Equation [4] is valid, this would imply that 
$$ f(\mathbf{u}) = \prod_{j=1}^M f(u_j) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [5] $$

Thus, if Equation [4] and [5] are valid, this would imply that $U_i$ is independent of $U_j$ if $i \neq j$.  However, I am suspecting if Equation [4] violates anything in probability theory?  It seems that the original conditional distribution is being "broken" apart.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is correct that
$$
\dfrac{ f({\bf x},{\bf u}) }{ f({\bf u}) }
\ =
\ \dfrac{ \prod_{j=1}^M f_j(x_j,u_j) }{ \prod_{j=1}^M f_j(u_j) }
$$
you cannot then equate denominators and conclude that
$$
f({\bf u})
\ =
\ \prod_{j=1}^M f_j(u_j)
$$

For example, suppose the $X_j$ are independent die-rolls, each $U_j$ is a copy of the *same* coin-flip (unrelated to the die-rolls), and $M \ge 2$.  Then everything in your post follows, except for the conclusion.  In particular $f({\bf u}) = \frac{1}{2}$ (if the $u_j$ are all equal) or $0$ (otherwise), but $\prod_{j=1}^M f_j(u_j) = 2^{-M}$.